# Declare actions before run tomcat inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to delete some files from a specific folder when I start tomcat from eclipse. Is there any way to do such a thing and NOT manually go there to delete the files? In visual studio you have the ability to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 options:

- You can make a script that delete these files and then start your Eclipse. Use that function to delete the file:

  rm -rf [path_to_the_file]/your_file

After, you can use use whatever method you want to run Eclipse from the script.

*Note: You can replace `your_file` by `*` to target all the files in the folder.*

- You can use the same command in the script which is launched when you launch your server
- If there is a Java class related to your action, you can add a delete method in it which be executed before launching your server.

Add this code before launching your server:

```
final File file_to_delete = new File("[path_to_the_file]/your_file");
    if (file_to_delete.exists()) {
        try {
            delete(file_to_delete);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
```

Add the following method in your class:

```
public static void delete(File file) throws IOException {

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        if (file.list().length == 0) {
            file.delete();
        } else {
            final String[] files = file.list();

            for (String temp : files) {
                final File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);
                delete(fileDelete);
            }
            if (file.list().length == 0) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    } else {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to start that inside eclipse when a start server (with 1 click)

Comment: Only when you starts a server?

Comment: How do you start your server?

Comment: From the server perspective there is a green button named start

Comment: Does it call one of your Java class in which you define the connection parameters?

Comment: Yes, there is a file with connection parameters but has nothing to do with what I want to do. Just when I press the green button to call somehow your batch file or whatever else and do some actions like delete some files from a specific directory. Sure, one solution is just write a batch file and just before start the tomcat to click on this batch file and then start the server. Any other solution?

Comment: If it is a Java class with a init method for your server, you can add a call to a delete method which can do the job. If it fits you, I have the method

Comment: I don't have any specific class. I just press the green button. Maybe I could put your command to the build.xml when I clean the project.

Comment: Yes of course, you just have to find which script is executed when you click on that green button to launch your server and add the command before it's launched. You can replace `your_file` by `*` if you want to delete everything that is in the directory